# Nginx: Перенаправление на другую папку

Tags: nginx

Структура моего преокта:

```
index.php
\web
    |
    |----\111
    |    |---- index.php
    |
    |----\222
         |---- index.php
```

Я хочу попасть в папку 111 и 222 используя следующую структуру ссылки:

1. http://example.com/wp111 (для web/111 папки)
2. http://example.com/wp222 (для web/222 папки)

Текущие настройки:

```
location ~ ^/wp(.*) {
    try_files $uri /web/$1?$query_string;
}
```

1. Работает только когда имеется символ `/` в конце (пример: example.com/wp111/ )
2. Автоматически перенаправляет меня на `example.com/web/111` когда в конце нет символа `/` (пример: example.com/wp111 )

Помогите с правильными настройками

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить `/` в `/web/$1/?$query_string;`